# bypass SSL CA checking

Tags: android, ssl, genymotion

I want to bypass CA checking on genymotion to force close source apk use my api.
But ssl/tls avoid to me with this notice on Burp Suit :

```
the client failed to negotiate a tls connection received fatal alert certificate unknown
```

Could you please help me to bypass SSL CA checking in genymotion app?

Also I removed all trusted CA on genymotion android and add my crt. but it still send me the above error.

Comment: which android version do you use?

Comment: 10 @FarzaneKhazaei

Comment: "I want to bypass CA checking" You shouldn't. This removes all interest in using TLS, you should then just go back to HTTP because pretending to do TLS without checking certificates validity is very snake oil security.

Comment: It's just for development @PatrickMevzek. Do you have any solution?

Comment: Then don't use HTTPS at all, just use HTTP. That is a solution.

Comment: try to install the latest version of Burpsuite from the official website.